# Rspec Test for JSON post Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Controller: payments_controller.rb

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  # This is needed to have Postman work
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
  render json: 'not_found', status: :not_found

  def create
    new_payment = Payment.new(new_params)
    current_loan = Loan.find(new_params[:loan_id])

    if Payment.valid?(new_payment, current_loan) 
      Payment.received(new_payment, current_loan)
      current_loan.save
        new_payment.save
        redirect_to '/loans'
    else 
      raise 'Amount entered is above the remaining balance'
    end
  end    

end
```

This method works when I test it in Postman. However, I can't seem to write a test for it that passes. I currently have:

payments_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe PaymentsController, type: :controller do

  describe "#create", :type => :request do 
    let!(:loan) {Loan.create!(id: 1, funded_amount: 500.0)}
    params = '{"payment":{"amount":400, "loan_id":2}}'

    it 'creates and saves a payment while saving the associated fund_amount of the loan' do
      post "/payments", params.to_json, {'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json'}
      expect(loan.funded_amount).to eql(600.0)
    end
  end
end
```

The error is:

```
Failure/Error: post "/payments", params.to_json, {'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json'}
 ActionController::ParameterMissing:
   param is missing or the value is empty: payment
```

Valid parameters (that work with Postman) are:

```
{"payment":{"amount":400,"loan_id":2}}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

*** UPDATE ****

After messing around with this for a while, I finally got it to work with this:

```
describe "#create", :type => :request do 
  let!(:loan) {Loan.create!(id: 1, funded_amount: 500.0)}

  it 'creates and saves a payment while saving the associated fund_amount of the loan' do
    json = { :format => 'json', :payment => { :amount => 200.0, :loan_id => 1 } }
    post '/payments', json
    loan.reload
    expect(loan.funded_amount).to eql(300.0)
  end
end
```

Comment: ` current_loan = Loan.find(new_params[:loan_id])
    if Payment.valid?(new_payment, current_loan)` 

im just wonder how u passing whole object ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in your params like this.

```
it 'creates and saves a payment while saving the associated fund_amount of the loan' do
  post "/payments", payment: { amount: 400, loan_id: 1 }, {'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json'}
  expect(loan.funded_amount).to eql(600.0)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I don't think it likes the payment: {amount: 400, loan_id: 1} not being in quotes. I get this error: Desktop/payments_challenge/spec/controllers/payments_controller_spec.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => (SyntaxError)

Comment: Hm can you try this? `{ payment: { amount: 400, loan_id: 1 } }`